# Upgrade VelocityTools 2.0 new tools.xml doesn't load

Tags: velocity

I'm switching to VelocityTools 2.0 but the new tools.xml doesn't load. I replaced toolbox.xml and now I use tools.xml but when I run the server I get:

> "XMLToolboxManager:100: XMLToolboxManager has been deprecated. Please
>   use org.apache.velocity.tools.ToolboxFactory instead.
>
> ServletToolboxManager:131: ServletToolboxManager has been deprecated.
>   Please use org.apache.velocity.tools.ToolboxFactory instead."

How can I use the ToolboxFactory? XMLToolboxManager or ServletToolboxManager are not referenced anywhere in my code so I can't simply replace the classes.

When I use toolbox.xml with VelocityTools 2.0 it works just fine, but I need to get the new xml syntax work in tools.xml

My bean definition in velocity.xml looks like this:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
         <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutView</value>
    </property>
    <property name="contentType">
        <value>text/html;charset=UTF-8</value>
    </property> 
    <property name="cache"><value>true</value></property>
    <property name="prefix"><value></value></property>
    <property name="suffix"><value>.vm</value></property> 
    <property name="toolboxConfigLocation"><value>/WEB-INF/tools.xml</value></property> 
</bean>
```

I tried removing the property for "toolboxConfigLocation" from the bean and hoped that the default tools.xml will be available, but when I tried to use i.e $math didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Can someone help please?

Comment: same warning happened in one old velocity code, tried many ways with xml, but could not solve it, I just needed linktool, solved like this https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-comparing-template-engines/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jeroenreijn/examples/configuration/WebMvcConfig.java#L138